# Ubuntu Server Virtualization on Redhat Linux

Tags: server, virtualization

Will Ubuntu Server 12.04 supports virtualization on Redhat Enterprise Linux.
I am facing a problem in Ubuntu Server 12.04. Ubuntu is not allowing me to get into admin rights.

Can you please help us.

Comment: Hello, can you please give soe more details on how you installed Ubuntu under Red Hat, what procedure you are following to "get into admin rights", and any error messages that you are seeing when you try this.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will work fine in a virtual machine. The host OS is irrelevant.

If by 'admin rights' you mean using the root user, that's a separate issue. Ubuntu installs with the root user not being someone you can log in as directly. To run commands with root privileges, you would use the `sudo` command as your regular user, who is in the sudo group.

You can configure the system such that you can log in as root, if necessary, by using sudo to gain a root shell, and then change the password for the root user.